# Print consecutive lines with a pattern

Tags: text, awk, sed, printing

I am trying to extract the first group of lines that start with #.
I just wanted to get the first pattern dynamically

example:
Input

```
# script:

something 

## Select the operation **  -
# mkfolders)    create      -
# copy)     copy Overlay  -
# bkp)      BKP of overlay  -

something

# commentary
# commentary
something
```

Output

```
## Select the operation **
# mkfolders)    create          -
# copy)         copy Overlay    -
# bkp)          BKP of overlay  -
```

I was using the following sed command for this

sed -n 5,8p file

The problem with it is that if there is any change in the file it is necessary to change the command. A dynamic solution for only the first group of consecultive lines would be welcome:

Any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `awk`'s paragraph mode

```
$ awk -v RS= '/^#/{print; exit}' ip.txt
# script:

$ awk -v RS= '/^##/{print; exit}' ip.txt
## Select the operation **  -
# mkfolders)    create      -
# copy)     copy Overlay  -
# bkp)      BKP of overlay  -
```

- `-v RS=` When RS is set to empty string, one or more consecutive empty lines is used as input record separator
- `/^##/` input record starting with `##`

  - `print; exit` print the input record and then exit as only first such record is needed

Question is somewhat unclear, below code would print first record that has `#` character in two consecutive lines

```
$ awk -v RS= '/#[^\n]+\n#/{print; exit}' ip.txt
## Select the operation **  -
# mkfolders)    create      -
# copy)     copy Overlay  -
# bkp)      BKP of overlay  -
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/^\s*#/!b;:a;N;/^\s[^#]/M!ba;/^(\s*#.*\n#[^\n]*).*/!b;s//\1/p;q' file
```

Forget lines that do not begin with `#`. Collect subsequent lines in the pattern space until a line that does not begin with a `#` or the end-of-file condition. If the collection is less than two lines, forget them and repeat. Otherwise, remove the last line if it does not begin with `#`, print the collection and quit.